# JS: addEventListener in class constructor

Tags: javascript, constructor, event-handling

I am coding a comment system. I met an issue in building `Like Button`.

1. like button is a font awesome `<i>` tag
2. author cannot like his own post
3. one user can only like one post once
4. click to like button, change its solid colour fill by toggling class.

The code I have done is tremendous, don't bother reading the code snippets below, I just provide it to allow you to see what's going on.

---

```js
// querySelector -> element
function proxy(el){
  el.oneEventListener = (event, func) => {
    if(el.lastEventListener == null){
      el.lastEventListener = {};
    }
    if(el.lastEventListener[event] != null){
      el.removeEventListener(event, el.lastEventListener[event]);
    }
    el.addEventListener(event, func);
    el.lastEventListener[event] = func;
  }
  return el;
}

// querySelectorAll -> NodeList
function proxyAll(el){
  el.forEach(ele=>{
    ele = proxy(ele);
  });
  return el;
}

/*
once proxy is implemented, by oneEventListener, 
only one event listener of particular type will exist on that element,
if you call addEventListener, proxy doesn't interfer it.
which the eventlistener added will work normally.
*/

// proxy query selector
const pqs = function(str){
  return proxy(document.querySelector(str));
}

// proxy query selector all
const pqsa = function(str){
  return proxyAll(document.querySelectorAll(str));
}
// end import

// optimization
// separate host comment and reply
// comment should have liked

class Author{
    constructor(name, avatar_link, profile_link){
        // avatar and profile are urls
        this.name = name;
        this.avatar = avatar_link;  // url to image
        this.profile = profile_link; // url to profile
    }
}

/* like system
1. like button is an <i> tag 
2. author cannot like his own post
3. one user can only like one post once
4. click means to switch state which trigger comment-checked class
*/

class LikeButton{
    // element, number element, likes, liked by this visitor, host (author object)
    constructor(el, num_el, likes, liked, host_author){
        this.el = proxy(el);
        this.num_el = num_el;
        this.likes = likes;
        this.liked = liked;
        this.host_author = host_author;

        // this.el.oneEventListener('click', function(){
        //  console.log('here');
        //  if(this.liked){
        //      this.unlike();
        //  }else{
        //      if(!this.like()){
        //          return
        //      }
        //  }
        //  this.liked = !this.liked;
        // });

        // this.like();
    }

    like(){
        if(this.host_author === visitor){
            window.alert("You cannot like your own post");
            return false;
        }else{
            this.likes++;
            console.log(this.el);
            this.el.classList.add('comment-checked');
            this.num_el.innerHTML = this.likes;
            return true;
        }
    }

    unlike(){
        this.likes--;
        this.num_el.innerHTML = this.likes;
        this.el.classList.remove('comment-checked');
        return true;
    }
}

class Reply{
    constructor(author, ago, content, by_author, likes, author_liked){
        this.author = author;
        this.ago = ago;
        this.content = content;
        this.by_author = by_author;
        this.likes = likes;
        this.author_liked = author_liked;
    }
}

// a comment is a reply
// act as host of replys parsed in dom
class Comment extends Reply{
    constructor(author, ago, content, by_author, likes, author_liked, comment_container){
        super(author, ago, content, by_author, likes, author_liked);

        this.comment_container = comment_container;
        this.replys = [];
    }

    add_reply(author, ago, content, by_author, likes, author_liked){
        this.replys.push(new Reply(author, ago, content, by_author, likes, author_liked));
        return this;
    }

    parse(container){
        let ul1 = document.createElement('ul');
        ul1.setAttribute('id', 'comments-list');
        ul1.setAttribute('class', 'comments-list');

        let li1 = document.createElement('li');

        let div1 = document.createElement('div');
        div1.setAttribute('class', 'comment-main-level'); 

        let div2 = document.createElement('div');
        div2.setAttribute('class', 'comment-avatar');

        let img1 = document.createElement('img');
        img1.setAttribute('src', this.author.avatar);

        let div3 = document.createElement('div');
        div3.setAttribute('class', 'comment-box');

        let div4 = document.createElement('div');
        div4.setAttribute('class', 'comment-head');

        let h6 = document.createElement('h6');
        h6.setAttribute('class', 'comment-name');

        let a1 = document.createElement('a');
        a1.setAttribute('href', this.author.profile);
        a1.innerHTML = this.author.name;

        let span1 = document.createElement('span');
        span1.innerHTML = this.ago + ' ago';

        let i1 = document.createElement('i');
        i1.setAttribute('class', 'fa fa-reply');

        let i2 = document.createElement('i');
        i2.setAttribute('class', 'fa fa-heart');

        let i3 = document.createElement('i');
        i3.setAttribute('class', 'comment-likes');
        i3.innerHTML = this.likes;

        new LikeButton(
            i2,
            i3,
            this.likes,
            this.author_liked,
            this.author,
        );

        let div5 = document.createElement('div');
        div5.setAttribute('class', 'comment-content');
        div5.innerHTML = this.content;

        // reply list
        let ul2 = document.createElement('ul');
        ul2.setAttribute('class', 'comments-list reply-list');

        // construct
        this.comment_container.appendChild(ul1);
        ul1.appendChild(li1);
        li1.appendChild(div1);
        div1.appendChild(div2);
        div2.appendChild(img1);
        div1.appendChild(div3);
        div3.appendChild(div4);
        div4.appendChild(h6);
        h6.appendChild(a1);
        div4.appendChild(span1);
        div4.appendChild(i1);
        div4.appendChild(i2);
        div4.appendChild(i3);
        div3.appendChild(div5);

        li1.appendChild(ul2);

        this.replys.forEach(rep=>{
            let li2 = document.createElement('li');
            
            let div6 = document.createElement('div');
            div6.setAttribute('class', 'comment-avatar');

            let img2 = document.createElement('img');
            img2.setAttribute('src', rep.author.avatar);

            let div7 = document.createElement('div');
            div7.setAttribute('class', 'comment-box');

            let div8 = document.createElement('div');
            div8.setAttribute('class', 'comment-head');

            let h61 = document.createElement('h6');
            h61.setAttribute('class', 'comment-name');

            let a2 = document.createElement('a');
            a2.setAttribute('href', rep.author.profile);
            a2.innerHTML = rep.author.name;

            let span2 = document.createElement('span');
            span2.innerHTML = rep.ago + ' ago';

            let i4 = document.createElement('i');
            i4.setAttribute('class', 'fa fa-reply');

            let i5 = document.createElement('i');
            i5.setAttribute('class', 'fa fa-heart');

            let i6 = document.createElement('i');
            i6.setAttribute('class', 'comment-likes');
            i6.innerHTML = rep.likes;

            new LikeButton(
                i5,
                i6,
                rep.likes,
                rep.author_liked,
                rep.author,
            );
            
            let div9 = document.createElement('div');
            div9.setAttribute('class', 'comment-content');
            div9.innerHTML = rep.content;

            ul2.appendChild(li2);
            li2.appendChild(div6);
            div6.appendChild(img2);
            li2.appendChild(div7);
            div7.appendChild(div8);
            div8.appendChild(h61);
            h61.appendChild(a2);
            div8.appendChild(span2);
            div8.appendChild(i4);
            div8.appendChild(i5);
            div8.appendChild(i6);
            div7.appendChild(div9);
        });
    }
}

var con = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit omnis animi et iure laudantium vitae, praesentium optio, sapiente distinctio illo?";

const comment_wrapper = pqs('.comments-container');

const user1 = new Author(
    'Agustin Ortiz', 
    "http://i9.photobucket.com/albums/a88/creaticode/avatar_1_zps8e1c80cd.jpg",
    '#'
);

const user2 = new Author(
    'Lorena Rojero', 
    "http://i9.photobucket.com/albums/a88/creaticode/avatar_2_zps7de12f8b.jpg",
    '#'
);

// current visiting user, an author onject
const visitor = user2;

// var comment1 = 
// (new Comment(
//  user1,  
//  "20 minutes",
//  con,
//  true,
//  1,
//  false,
//  comment_wrapper
// ))
// .add_reply(
//  user2,
//  "10 minutes",
//  con, 
//  false,
//  2,
//  true,
// )
// .add_reply(
//  user1, 
//  "10 minutes",
//  con,
//  true,
//  3,
//  false, 
// );

var comment2 = 
(new Comment(
    user1,
    "10 minutes",
    con,
    true,
    4,
    false, 
    comment_wrapper
));

// comment1.parse();

comment2.parse();
```

```css
/*body{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background: darkgrey;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

#shelf-image-comments{
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    background: wheat;
}

.comment{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background: grey;
}*/

/**
 * Oscuro: #283035
 * Azul: #03658c
 * Detalle: #c7cacb
 * Fondo: #dee1e3
 ----------------------------------*/
 * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
 }

 a {
    color: #03658c;
    text-decoration: none;
 }

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Roboto', Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif, Verdana;
    background: #dee1e3;
}

/** ====================
 * Lista de Comentarios
 =======================*/
.comments-container {
    margin: 60px auto 15px;
    width: 768px;
}

.comments-container h1 {
    font-size: 36px;
    color: #283035;
    font-weight: 400;
}

.comments-container h1 a {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.comments-list {
    margin-top: 30px;
    position: relative;
}

/**
 * Lineas / Detalles
 -----------------------*/
.comments-list:before {
    content: '';
    width: 2px;
    height: 100%;
    background: #c7cacb;
    position: absolute;
    left: 32px;
    top: 0;
}

.comments-list:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    background: #c7cacb;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 27px;
    width: 7px;
    height: 7px;
    border: 3px solid #dee1e3;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.reply-list:before, .reply-list:after {display: none;}
.reply-list li:before {
    content: '';
    width: 60px;
    height: 2px;
    background: #c7cacb;
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
    left: -55px;
}


.comments-list li {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}

.comments-list li:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
}

.reply-list {
    padding-left: 88px;
    clear: both;
    margin-top: 15px;
}
/**
 * Avatar
 ---------------------------*/
.comments-list .comment-avatar {
    width: 65px;
    height: 65px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 99;
    float: left;
    border: 3px solid #FFF;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    overflow: hidden;
}

.comments-list .comment-avatar img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.reply-list .comment-avatar {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}

.comment-main-level:after {
    content: '';
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
/**
 * Caja del Comentario
 ---------------------------*/
.comments-list .comment-box {
    width: 680px;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
}

.comments-list .comment-box:before, .comments-list .comment-box:after {
    content: '';
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    border-width: 10px 12px 10px 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: transparent #FCFCFC;
    top: 8px;
    left: -11px;
}

.comments-list .comment-box:before {
    border-width: 11px 13px 11px 0;
    border-color: transparent rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    left: -12px;
}

.reply-list .comment-box {
    width: 610px;
}
.comment-box .comment-head {
    background: #FCFCFC;
    padding: 10px 12px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #E5E5E5;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
}

.comment-box .comment-head i {
    float: right;
    margin-left: 14px;
    position: relative;
    top: 2px;
    color: #A6A6A6;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition: color 0.3s ease;
    -o-transition: color 0.3s ease;
    transition: color 0.3s ease;
}

.comment-box .comment-head .comment-likes{
    font-style: normal;
    color: #A6A6A6;
}

.comment-box .comment-head i:hover {
    color: #03658c;
}

.comment-checked{
    color: #03658c !important;
}

.comment-box .comment-name {
    color: #283035;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 700;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.comment-box .comment-name a {
    color: #283035;
}

.comment-box .comment-head span {
    float: left;
    color: #999;
    font-size: 13px;
    position: relative;
    top: 1px;
}

.comment-box .comment-content {
    background: #FFF;
    padding: 12px;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #595959;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
    border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
}

.comment-box .comment-name.by-author, .comment-box .comment-name.by-author a {color: #03658c;}
.comment-box .comment-name.by-author:after {
    content: 'autor';
    background: #03658c;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 3px 5px;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin-left: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

/** =====================
 * Responsive
 ========================*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 766px) {
    .comments-container {
        width: 480px;
    }

    .comments-list .comment-box {
        width: 390px;
    }

    .reply-list .comment-box {
        width: 320px;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
    <!-- Fuentes de Google -->
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <!-- Iconos -->
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="comment.css" />
</head>
<body>

<!-- <div id="shelf-image-comments">
    <div class="comment">
        <lable>Weilory</lable><p>Here</p>
    </div>
</div> -->

<!-- Contenedor Principal -->
    <div class="comments-container">
        <h1>Comentarios <a href="http://creaticode.com">creaticode.com</a></h1>

        <!-- <ul id="comments-list" class="comments-list">
            <li>
                <div class="comment-main-level">
                    <div class="comment-avatar"><img src="http://i9.photobucket.com/albums/a88/creaticode/avatar_1_zps8e1c80cd.jpg" alt=""></div>
                    <div class="comment-box">
                        <div class="comment-head">
                            <h6 class="comment-name by-author"><a href="http://creaticode.com/blog">Agustin Ortiz</a></h6>
                            <span>hace 20 minutos</span>
                            <i class="fa fa-reply"></i>
                            <i class="fa fa-heart"></i>
                            <i class="comment-likes">2</i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="comment-content">
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit omnis animi et iure laudantium vitae, praesentium optio, sapiente distinctio illo?
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <ul class="comments-list reply-list">
                    <li>
                        <div class="comment-avatar"><img src="http://i9.photobucket.com/albums/a88/creaticode/avatar_2_zps7de12f8b.jpg" alt=""></div>
                        <div class="comment-box">
                            <div class="comment-head">
                                <h6 class="comment-name"><a href="http://creaticode.com/blog">Lorena Rojero</a></h6>
                                <span>hace 10 minutos</span>
                                <i class="fa fa-reply"></i>
                                <i class="fa fa-heart"></i>
                                <i class="comment-likes">2</i>
                            </div>
                            <div class="comment-content">
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit omnis animi et iure laudantium vitae, praesentium optio, sapiente distinctio illo?
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <div class="comment-avatar"><img src="http://i9.photobucket.com/albums/a88/creaticode/avatar_1_zps8e1c80cd.jpg" alt=""></div>
                        <div class="comment-box">
                            <div class="comment-head">
                                <h6 class="comment-name by-author"><a href="http://creaticode.com/blog">Agustin Ortiz</a></h6>
                                <span>hace 10 minutos</span>
                                <i class="fa fa-reply"></i>
                                <i class="fa fa-heart"></i>
                                <i class="comment-likes">2</i>
                            </div>
                            <div class="comment-content">
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit omnis animi et iure laudantium vitae, praesentium optio, sapiente distinctio illo?
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li>
                <div class="comment-main-level">
                    <div class="comment-avatar"><img src="http://i9.photobucket.com/albums/a88/creaticode/avatar_2_zps7de12f8b.jpg" alt=""></div>
                    <div class="comment-box">
                        <div class="comment-head">
                            <h6 class="comment-name"><a href="http://creaticode.com/blog">Lorena Rojero</a></h6>
                            <span>hace 10 minutos</span>
                            <i class="fa fa-reply"></i>
                            <i class="fa fa-heart"></i>
                            <i class="comment-likes">2</i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="comment-content">
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit omnis animi et iure laudantium vitae, praesentium optio, sapiente distinctio illo?
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul> -->
        
    </div>

<script src="comment.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

### The Expected Output, is that when I click on the `like button`, it should turn blue, and the number left should increment 1.

The `LikeButton` is constructed by following:

```js
class LikeButton{
    // element, number display element, likes, whether liked by this visitor, host (author object)
    constructor(el, num_el, likes, liked, host_author){
        this.el = proxy(el);
        this.num_el = num_el;
        this.likes = likes;
        this.liked = liked;
        this.host_author = host_author;

        this.el.oneEventListener('click', function(){
            console.log('here');
            if(this.liked){
                this.unlike();
            }else{
                if(!this.like()){
                    return
                }
            }
            this.liked = !this.liked;
        });
        this.like();
    }

    like(){
        if(this.host_author === visitor){
            window.alert("You cannot like your own post");
            return false;
        }else{
            this.likes++;
            console.log(this.el);
            this.el.classList.add('comment-checked');
            this.num_el.innerHTML = this.likes;
            return true;
        }
    }

    unlike(){
        this.likes--;
        this.num_el.innerHTML = this.likes;
        this.el.classList.remove('comment-checked');
        return true;
    }
}
```

You may have noticed that I applied weird method`proxy` and `oneEventListener`, they are singleton event type listeners **which only allow one click event on one element**, archived by following:

```js
// querySelector -> element
function proxy(el){
  el.oneEventListener = (event, func) => {
    if(el.lastEventListener == null){
      el.lastEventListener = {};
    }
    if(el.lastEventListener[event] != null){
      el.removeEventListener(event, el.lastEventListener[event]);
    }
    el.addEventListener(event, func);
    el.lastEventListener[event] = func;
  }
  return el;
}

// querySelectorAll -> NodeList
function proxyAll(el){
  el.forEach(ele=>{
    ele = proxy(ele);
  });
  return el;
}
```

**it won't make a difference if I switch `oneEventListener` to `addEventListener`**, for example, following code

```js
class LikeButton{
    // element, number display element, likes, whether liked by this visitor, host (author object)
    constructor(el, num_el, likes, liked, host_author){
        this.el = el;
        this.num_el = num_el;
        this.likes = likes;
        this.liked = liked;
        this.host_author = host_author;

        this.el.addEventListener('click', function(){
            console.log('here');
            if(this.liked){
                this.unlike();
            }else{
                if(!this.like()){
                    return
                }
            }
            this.liked = !this.liked;
        });
        this.like();
    }

    like(){
        if(this.host_author === visitor){
            window.alert("You cannot like your own post");
            return false;
        }else{
            this.likes++;
            console.log(this.el);
            this.el.classList.add('comment-checked');
            this.num_el.innerHTML = this.likes;
            return true;
        }
    }

    unlike(){
        this.likes--;
        this.num_el.innerHTML = this.likes;
        this.el.classList.remove('comment-checked');
        return true;
    }
}
```

When clicking on the `heart` like button, I am expecting at least `here` is logged into console, but nothing happened, thus `addEventListener` in `LikeButton constructor` did not work at all.

I tried both arrow function and function. didn't workout.

Thank you so much for reading to the end. I will be so touched if someone offer some suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you're having is actually a shadowing of references.
The "this" keyword doesn't apply to the class anymore. It is referring to the element that the event is routed to.
You can pass the reference that you want to be bound to the "this" keyword as a parameter to the function of addEventListener like so:

```
this.el.addEventListener('click', function(){
            console.log('here');
            if(this.liked){
                this.unlike();
            }else{
                if(!this.like()){
                    return
                }
            }
            this.liked = !this.liked;
        }.bind(this));
```

Again, to clarify it:

You have a class and you have an element that you encapsulate in it (analogous to, for example, a nut and a nutshell).
"This" in the constructor refers to your class and the second "this" to your HTML element in your click handler.